# Javascript prototype inheritance and "instanceof"

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

I just cannot understand, why in object inheritance "instanceof" fails to evaluate "children"-objects as instances of parent prototypes. For example:

```
function Parent(property) {
    this.property = property;
}

function Child(property) {
    Parent.call(property);
}

const child = new Child("");

console.log(child instanceof Child); // of course, true
console.log(child instanceof Parent); // false. But why???
```

As for inheritance of classes (or rather of what is deemed to be classes in JS), the situation is different:

```
class Parent {
    constructor(property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(property) {
        super(property);
    }
}

const child = new Child("");

console.log(child instanceof Child); // true
console.log(child instanceof Parent); // also true!!!
```

What is the cause of this difference? Is it possible to create children-objects so that they were correctly recognised as instances of their parent prototypes (without resorting to classes)?

Comment: Your first example doesn't use prototypical inheritance, that's why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example is, quite simply, not remotely close to how "prototypal inheritance" works in Javascript.

For one thing, `Parent.call(property)` surely isn't what you meant. This calls `Parent` with its `this` set to `property`, and no arguments passed, which definitely isn't what you want. I suspect you mean `Parent.call(this, property)` - which calls `Parent` with the same `this` as is passed to `Child`, and passing through the `property` argument. But this isn't anything to do with "inheritance".

The [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator simply checks an object's "prototype chain" to see if the relevant object (the `prototype` property of the "class" you're testing against) appears anywhere. The only way to manipulate objects to affect the `instanceof` operator is to alter the prototype chain.

There are a number of ways to do this, but the standard way to "fake" something like class-based inheritance in JS, pre-ES6, would have been like this:

```js
function Parent(property) {
    this.property = property;
}

function Child(property) {
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

const child = new Child("");

console.log(child instanceof Child);
console.log(child instanceof Parent);
```

which manually makes all objects constructed from `Child` delegate to `Object.create(Parent.prototype)`, which itself is an object (one otherwise completely empty and with no special properties) that "inherits" from `Parent.prototype`. So now when `instanceof` checks the prototype chain, it finds what it's looking for, and therefore returns `true`, as you can see from the above snippet.

Of course, if you really do want class-based inheritance in JS (which I personally wouldn't recommend, but is certainly popular), the ES6 `class` syntax gives a much nicer syntactic sugar so you don't have to manually mess with the prototype chain as above. But be aware that that's essentially what's going on "under the hood" with ES6 classes.

I strongly recommend [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes) book (freely available to read online) for much deeper explanations of all this. Chapter 5 is the most relevant one in this context.

Comment: Lots of thanks for a 100% informative and clear answer! You've helped me a lot.

Comment: Is it OK to use "Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, Parent.prototype);" instead of "Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);" (in your example)? I tried, it works.
And the difference is in the following: when I use "setPrototypeOf" and then check in the console "Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Child.prototype)", I can see the constructor property inside, but when I use "Object.create" (like in your example), this check does not show the constructor.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again ... but why the results of "Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Child.prototype)" are different if to use "Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, Parent.prototype);" and "Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);"? See above (I've just edited the comment).

Comment: "Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, Parent.prototype);" seems to be the same as "Child.prototype.__proto__ = Parent.prototype;", but different from "Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);": in the first two cases, constructor is shown when to check "Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Child.prototype)"; in the third case, Child seems to lose its own constructor property...

Comment: That's because the `Child.prototype` which JS automatically creates for you includes, a `constructor` property. The first two examples simply change that object's prototype, whereas the one with `Object.create` overrides the object completely (creates a completely empty object with the correct prototype).